# Error Trailing Characters in Ubuntu

Tags: vim, ubuntu

I'm trying to set up my VIMRC (gvim on Ubuntu 11.10)file which contains just 2 lines (as of now)

```
set ruler
set number
```

I keep getting this error:

```
line 1:
E488: Trailing characters: number^M 
line  2: 
E488: Trailing characters: ruler^M
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Did you copy your file from a Windows box, by any chance?

Comment: No. Although I do intend to use the same vimrc as I use in Windows. Is there an issue with that?

Comment: Yes - it sounds like it's got Windows line terminators.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As pointed out by the comment, it seems that you've got some `\r` characters from a windows configuration. To solve this use:

```
dos2unix <file>
```

Answer (score 11):

Open the vimrc file in vim (this will probably work with errors.  If it doesn't then move _vimrc to myVimrc):

```
vim _vimrc
```

Then run this ex command:

```
:set fileformat=unix
```

---

Dos2Unix didn't work for me.  *I think that dos2unix only works with ANSI files.*

```
dos2unix <file>
```